# Convert XML with Attributes to Object with LINQ

Tags: c#, xml, linq, linq-to-xml

I have an XML file setup as follows:

```
<products>
<product>
    <tradegood id = "11">Textiles</tradegood>
    <baseprice>3000</baseprice>
    <purchaseDMs>
        <mod type="A">-7</mod>
        <mod type="a">-5</mod>
        <mod type="i">-3</mod>
    </purchaseDMs>
    <resaleDMs>
        <mod type="A">-6</mod>
        <mod type="a">1</mod>
        <mod type="R">3</mod>
    </resaleDMs>
    <quantity>90</quantity>
</product>
```

And I am using LINQ to XML as follows:

```
  XDocument productList = XDocument.Load("products.xml");

  List<Product> products = 
                (from objProduct in productList.Element("products").Elements("product")
                    select new Product
                    {
                         Id = int.Parse(objProduct.Element("tradegood").Attribute("id").Value),
                         ProductName = objProduct.Element("tradegood").Value,
                         BasePrice = double.Parse(objProduct.Element("baseprice").Value),
                         MaxQuantity = int.Parse(objProduct.Element("quantity").Value),
                         PurchaseDMs = (from _mods in objProduct.Element("purchaseDMs").Elements("mod")
                              select new 
                                {
                                key = _mods.Attribute("type").Value,
                                value = _mods.Value
                                }),
                         ResaleDMs = (from _mods in objProduct.Element("resaleDMs").Elements("mod")
                              select new 
                                {
                                key = _mods.Attribute("type").Value,
                                value = _mods.Value
                                })
                      }).ToList;
```

The following is the product class:

```
public class Product
{
    private string p_ProductName;
    private double p_BasePrice;
    private int p_MaxQuantity;
    private double p_ActualValue;
    private int p_id;
    private int p_Quantity;

    public string ProductName
    {
        get { return p_ProductName; }
        set { p_ProductName = value; }
    }
    public double BasePrice
    {
        get { return p_BasePrice; }
        set { p_BasePrice = value; }
    }
    public int MaxQuantity
    {
        get { return p_MaxQuantity; }
        set { p_MaxQuantity = value; }
    }
    public int QuantityAvailable 
    {
        get { return p_Quantity; }
        set { p_Quantity = value; }
    }
    public double ActualValue
    {
        get { return p_ActualValue; }
        set { p_ActualValue = value; }
    }
    public int Id
    {
        get { return p_id; }
        set { p_id = value; }
    }

    public Dictionary<string, int> ResaleDMs;
    public Dictionary<string, int> PurchaseDMs;
}
```

The only part I can't figure out how to get working is ResaleDMs and PurchaseDMs.

The `select` statements are both showing "Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable' to 'System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary'. An explicit conversion exists (are you missing a cast?)"

Can anyone help me figure this out? How do I initialize those fields?

Comment: I would have to assume you just need to call `ToDictionary` on the `IEnumerable` returned by each of the select queries: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb549277%28v=vs.100%29.aspx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason you are getting that exception is because you are assigning the dictionary properties the value of an IEnumerable projection.

When you do:

```
select new 
{
  key = _mods.Attribute("type").Value,
  value = _mods.Value
}
```

You are just creating a new anonymous object type with two properties (key & value). This does not directly correlate to a dictionary entry object type. Instead you could use the ToDictionary extension method..

```
PurchaseDMs = objProduct.Element("purchaseDMs").Elements("mod")
                        .ToDictionary(e => e.Attribute("type").Value, e => Convert.ToInt32(e.Value)),
ResaleDMs = objProduct.Element("resaleDMs").Elements("mod")
                      .ToDictionary(e => e.Attribute("type").Value, e => Convert.ToInt32(e.Value))
```

Comment: Thank you. I don't know how many variations on this I tried and could not get the correct syntax.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should be able to get the IEnumerable by using ToArray():

```
List<Product> products = 
            (from objProduct in productList.Element("products").Elements("product")
                select new Product
                {
                     Id = int.Parse(objProduct.Element("tradegood").Attribute("ID").Value),
                     ProductName = objProduct.Element("tradegood").Value,
                     BasePrice = double.Parse(objProduct.Element("baseprice").Value),
                     MaxQuantity = int.Parse(objProduct.Element("quantity").Value),
                     PurchaseDMs = (from _mods in objProduct.Element("purchaseDMs").Elements("mod")
                          select new 
                            {
                            key = _mods.Attribute("type").Value,
                            value = _mods.Value
                            }),
                     ResaleDMs = (from _mods in objProduct.Element("resaleDMs").Elements("mod")
                          select new 
                            {
                            key = _mods.Attribute("type").Value,
                            value = _mods.Value
                            })
                  }).ToArray();
```